# Setting moduleId in Angular 2 component not working

Tags: angular, relative-path

I'm trying to setup relative paths in Angular 2 as described in the [COMPONENT-RELATIVE PATHS](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html) section of the Angular 2 documentation. In my component I set the moduleId in the decorator

```
@Component({
    selector: 'SpecifiedInsuredExtra',
    moduleId: module.id, 
    templateUrl: './Templates/SpecifiedInsuredExtra-1.0.2.html',
    providers: [SpecifiedInsuredExtraService]
})
```

My tsconfig.json sets the module to commonjs

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "Angular/Transpiled/"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

Then I'm using a gulp task to minify my component js files

```
gulp.task('SpecifiedInsuredExtraAngularJs', ["CleanSpecifiedInsuredExtraJs"], function () {
    util.log('Creating specifiedinsuredextra-1.0.2.min.js.');

    var builder = new Builder('', './Angular/Configurations/SpecifiedInsuredExtraConfiguration.js');

    return builder
    .buildStatic(paths.transpiled + '/Applications/SpecifiedInsuredExtra.js', paths.scripts + 'specifiedinsuredextra-1.0.2.min.js', { minify: true, sourceMaps: true })
    .then(function () {
        console.log('Build complete');
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Build error');
        console.log(err);
    });
});

gulp.task('SpecifiedInsuredExtraJs', ["SpecifiedInsuredExtraAngularJs"], function () {
    util.log('Creating specifiedinsuredextra-1.0.2.min.js.');

    return gulp.src(
    [
        './wwwroot/Scripts/specifiedinsuredextra.min.js'
    ])
    .pipe(concat('specifiedinsuredextra-1.0.2.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify()).pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts));
});
```

As far as I understand relatave paths should now work, but when I run the application I'm getting a `404 http response` because the template was not found in the root of the application. When I log the `module` object to the console, the id is set to 13 which I would expect should be set to the relative path

[image]

Is there something that I'm missing here?

Comment: Are you using wwwroot to serve your pages when you run your app???

Comment: I have a domain with a lot of sub apps, this is just one of those apps which pages are served from inetpub/wwwroot/[The Main folder]/[The Sub App folder]/wwwroot